# Finding all max values in (tree)map with streams and lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, treemap

So I have to find the max value(s) in a map in java with streams and lambda. Finding one max value is not a problem, but how can I find multiple?
Example:
Treemap<String, Integer> with elements "e" = 2, "i" = 1, "a" = 2,
My current solution gives me "a" = 2, but I want "a" = 2, "e" = 2

My code:

```
Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new Treemap<>();
frequencies.put("e", 2);//I don't put the values in like this but it'll do to test
frequencies.put("i", 1);
frequencies.put("a", 2);
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> maxEntry = frequencies.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());//frequencies is the TreeMap<String, Integer>
//I know this only searches one max value, here's my other attempt:
try (Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> stream = frequencies.entrySet().stream()) {
      stream
          .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (k, v) -> k, LinkedHashMap::new));
//I don't know what to do here, I somehow would have to get the result into a new list, but it still only returns one result
    }
```

Please let me know if im doing anything wrong.

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))` FYI it's `TreeMap`, not `Treemap`

Comment: ...`collect` to a `TreeMap` again and get `lastEntry` for your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have to find the max value(s) in a map in java with streams and lambda.

Here is one way to do it without a TreeMap.  It does a frequency count of containing Entries.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("z", -1, "b", 0, "r", -2,
        "s", 0, "j", 1, "a", 2, "i", 1, "e", 2);

Optional<Entry<Integer, List<Entry<String,Integer>>>> opt = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue))
        .entrySet().stream().max(Entry.comparingByKey());

System.out.println(opt.isPresent() ? opt.get().getValue() : "Empty List");
```

Prints

```
[a=2, e=2]
```

And just for fun you can bypass the initial map and create a stream of entries.  In reality, when you create your intitial Map you are creating Entry objects so no additional map overhead is involved here.

```
        
Builder<Entry<String, Integer>> entryStream = Stream.builder();

entryStream.add(Map.entry("b", 0));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("r", -2));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("s", 0));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("j", 1));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("a", 2));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("i", 1));
entryStream.add(Map.entry("e", 2));
```

At this point, it's the same as before except the stream is ready to invoke.

```
Optional<Entry<Integer, List<Entry<String, Integer>>>> opt =
                entryStream.build()
                        .collect(Collectors
                                .groupingBy(Entry::getValue))
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .max(Entry.comparingByKey());
        
System.out.println(opt.isPresent() ? opt.get().getValue() :
                "Empty List");
```

Prints as before

```
[a=2, e=2]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find the max frequency:

```
Optional<Integer> maxFreqOptional = frequencies.values()
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Then you can just collect all entries with this frequency as a value:

```
Integer maxFreq = maxFreqOptional.get(); // check if it's empty first
List<String> mostFrequent = frequencies.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(maxFreq))
    .map(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

Collect the entry stream into a `TreeMap` using the value (=frequency) as key and the original key as value. Use the cascaded `groupingBy` therefore. Then take the entry with the largest key:

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> map = frequencies.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()
    ));
Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> largest = map.lastEntry();
```

*Note: If your data set is large and you want to avoid building up this reverse map, you may prefer one of the other suggested solutions that iterate the map twice: Once to find the largest frequence, and then again to find all corresponding entries.*

Comment: @fps Thanks. It was `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: without `mapping`, this should really work to produce a `TreeMap<Integer, String> map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do filter by `maxEntry`'s value if present to get all `Map.Entry` of max value

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> res = frequencies.entrySet().stream()
                                 .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(maxEntry.get().getValue()))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Online demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJslHi--D)

Output: `[a=2, e=2]`

Answer (score 0):

As you only need the entries that match the max value, there's no gain in grouping all the entries of the map in a reverse map. You only need to discard all entries whose value doesn't match the max value.

Here's a succinct way to do it with lambdas:

```
Integer max = frequencies.isEmpty() ? 
              Integer.MIN_VALUE :
              Collections.max(frequencies.values());

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
frequencies.forEach((k, v) -> { if (v.equals(max)) result.add(k); });
```

So, in `max` you have the max value, while in `result` you have the keys that match the max value. This algorithm's time complexity is `O(n)` worst case, unlike the algorithms that group entries, which are all `O(nlogn)`.

The streams equivalent version is more verbose:

```
Integer max = frequencies.values().stream()
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
    .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

List<String> result = frequencies.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(max))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```